# PgAdmin is not showing in laragon

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, laragon

PgAdmin4 is not showing in **laragon->pgsql**

I dowload and add postgresql in **Laragon->bin** my version is 16.1-1. After adding it starts with server but PgAdmin4 is not showing in my **laragon->pgsql** menu. How can I solve this problem? [image][image][image][image]

Comment: Why are you upvoting yourself without answering the question? Please see below for correct answer and vote for that instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Laragon developer https://github.com/leokhoa has removed PGAdmin as it was too slow and to promote the use of dbeaver. See this link for reference https://github.com/leokhoa/laragon/issues/345.